# Swift 3 Dictionary JSON

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

in school we're creating a program to track Sailing Races.

I'm currently developing the GPS Tracker App for the sailing teams.
The JSON to send to our Api must look like this:

```
{"hash":"asdh832","positions":[{"longitude":13.340532999999999,"latitude":52.4965431,"time":1488182463461},{"longitude":13.3175489,"latitude":52.4927039,"time":1488195535705},{"longitude":13.3175489,"latitude":52.4927039,"time":1488195536657}]}
```

First the Hash for the Team and positions in a Array(if the smartphone doesn't have a internet connection atm to send them later)

I have a "positions" Array Dictionary:

```
    var positions = Array<Dictionary<String,String>>()
            positions.append(   ["longitude":String(location.coordinate.longitude),
                                 "latitude":String(location.coordinate.latitude),
                                 "time":String(Int64(location.timestamp.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000.0))])

// Times 2 to test
            positions.append(   ["longitude":String(location.coordinate.longitude),
                                 "latitude":String(location.coordinate.latitude),
                                 "time":String(Int64(location.timestamp.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000.0))])

    let data2 = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: positions, options: [])
                let dataString2 = String(data: data2,encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
                print(dataString2)
```

The Result of print(dataString2) is:

```
[{"latitude":"52.4965211222075","longitude":"13.3405919673345","time":"1488194768467"},{"latitude":"52.4965211222075","longitude":"13.3405919673345","time":"1488194768467"}]
```

which is correct. Now I want to combine it with a the Hash:

```
let params: Dictionary<String, String> = ["hash":"asdh832","positions": dataString2]
            let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params , options: [])
            let dataString = String(data: data,encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
```

but the now the result after "positions:" looks kinda weird:

```
{"hash":"asdh832","positions":"[{\"latitude\":\"52.4966040328522\",\"longitude\":\"13.3402242104124\",\"time\":\"1488195406482\"},{\"latitude\":\"52.4966040328522\",\"longitude\":\"13.3402242104124\",\"time\":\"1488195406482\"}]"}
```

without these extra " and \ it would be correct but I just don't know how to build it like this.

I'm using Swift 3 with Xcode 8.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make JSON string at last means don't create JSON string from Array positions instead of that set that Array with your `params` dictionary with key `positions` instead of setting string.

```
var positions = Array<Dictionary<String,String>>()
positions.append(["longitude":String(location.coordinate.longitude),
                  "latitude":String(location.coordinate.latitude),
                  "time":String(Int64(location.timestamp.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000.0))])


positions.append(["longitude":String(location.coordinate.longitude),
                  "latitude":String(location.coordinate.latitude),
                  "time":String(Int64(location.timestamp.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000.0))])

//Now set this positions array with positions key in params dictionary
let params: Dictionary<String, Any> = ["hash":"asdh832","positions": positions]
let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params , options: [])
let dataString = String(data: data,encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
```

Answer (score 0):

> The Result of print(dataString2) is: [...] which is correct.

No.

You're serialising `latitude`, `longitude` and `timestamp` as strings, while they should be numbers (notice the quotes).

> [...] but the now the result after "positions:" looks kinda weird

That's because you double serialise `dataString2`.

Do not call `JSONSerialization.data` twice but create one big `Dictionary<String, Any>` that contains all structured data and then perform the serialisation in one call.

Comment: Nirav D was faster but still thanks with the int for latidude etc. :) Don't know why i made them to Strings